# Converting nested dict into a single unchanging unique number

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on a minimax algorithm project and I am trying to find a way to save board values in a text file so they don't need to be calculated over and over again each time the program is tested. I have the board stored as a nested dictionary.

```
rows = {
    4:{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0},
    3:{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0},
    2:{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0},
    1:{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0},
    }
```

I tried doing this, which gives the desired result but is not at all optimized and I'm sure there is a way to do this better.

```
 rows = {
    4:{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0},
    3:{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0},
    2:{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0},
    1:{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0},
    }

e = []
for key in rows:
    e.append(list(rows[key].values()))
e=str(e)
e=e.replace ("[",""); e=e.replace ("]","")
e=e.replace (" ","")
e=e.replace (",","")
print(e)
```

Comment: You can use for example `json` module to save `rows` to file in Json format. Then use `json.load` to load the data back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map) is used to convert integers to strings:

```
res = ''.join(''.join(map(str, r.values())) for r in rows.values())
print(res)
```

Out:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
```